# Double integral substitution where the region of integration becomes a point

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to evaluate a double integral of some function over the region between the graphs $y=x^2$ and $y=\frac{x^2}{2}+1$.

$D=\{(x,y):-\sqrt2\leq x \leq \sqrt2, x^2\leq y \leq \frac{x^2}{2}+1\}$

The subsitution I am trying to make is
$$x^2=u$$
$$y=v$$

The way I visualise this substitution is folding around the $y$ axis from left to right and making the curves straight lines.

$$y=x^2 \rightarrow v=u$$

$$y=\frac{x^2}{2}+1 \rightarrow v=\frac{u}{2}+1$$

From there I get confused. The Jacobian is <s>always zero</s> $\pm \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}$ and $D$ became a single point $(2,2)$. Doesn't this make the integral zero?

Comment: The Jacobian of $(x,y)\mapsto (x^2,y)$ is always $0$ on $D$? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @MatthewPilling sorry, I made a mistake, its $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}$

Comment: What is the function that you are finding integral of? Given the substitution you are using, you need to be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \displaystyle D=\{(x,y):-\sqrt2\leq x \leq \sqrt2, x^2\leq y \leq \frac{x^2}{2}+1\}$

The integral is straightforward without change of variable. Coming to the change of variable that you are using,

$u = x^2, v = y$

The substitution you are using does not give one to one mapping between the original region and the region after transformation. In other words, note that substitution $u = x^2$ (given the bounds of $y$ is a function of $x^2$) leads to the original region for $x \lt 0$ and $x \gt 0$ map to the same region after change of variable. So you need to be careful while integrating a function over the given region. See the second example below.

The bounds are $0 \leq u \leq 2, u \leq v \leq \frac u 2 + 1$

Jacobian $|J| = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt u}$

So for example, if we were finding bound area of the region,

$ \displaystyle \int_{- \sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2} \int_{x^2}^{\frac {x^2} 2 + 1} 1 ~ dy ~ dx = \int_0^2 \int_u^{\frac u 2 + 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt u} ~ dv ~ du$

But say, you were integrating $f(x) = x$ over the given region. Due to symmetry of the original region about $x = 0$ and given $f(x) = x$ is an odd function,

$ \displaystyle \int_{- \sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2} \int_{x^2}^{\frac {x^2} 2 + 1} x ~ dy ~ dx = 0$

But after change of variable, when $x \lt 0$, the integrand is $ - \sqrt u$ and when $x \gt 0$, the integrand is $ \sqrt u$.

So, $I = I_1 + I_2 = 0$ where,

$ \displaystyle I_1 = \int_0^2 \int_u^{\frac u 2 + 1} -\frac{1}{2} ~ dv ~ du$

$ \displaystyle I_2 = \int_0^2 \int_u^{\frac u 2 + 1} \frac{1}{2} ~ dv ~ du$

Comment: That makes it a lot more clear, thanks!